# Vendor specific HID Usage Page code?

Tags: usb

I'd like to use a custom usage page ID with usb devices that may have different vendor and product ids so the devices will be detected solely by the usage page and the usage ids.  Is there a central registry for the vendor defined usage page id's starting with 0xFF or do I just have to select a random one and hope that there isn't a conflict in the future? Is there a way to tag the HID interface so that it is easily detectable in a way that won't have potential conflicts in the future?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, device identification should be done thru VID, PID, etc., not thru HID-specific descriptors. Also, currently it seems there are only 0xFF vendor-specific Usage Pages, as Usage Page is 16-bit:

*HID Usage Tables 1.12, 2004/10/28, pg15:*

```
 FF00-FFFF | Vendor-defined
```

*Device Class Definition for Human Interface Devices 1.11, 2001/06/27, pg17:*

```
A Usage is interpreted as a 32 bit unsigned value where the high order 16 bits
defines the Usage Page and the low order 16 bits defines a Usage ID. Usage IDs
are used to select individual Usage on a Usage Page.
```

Answer (score -2):

USB Implementers Forum is the only legal organisation to issue a vendor ID.
The owner of the vendor ID is responsible to handle PIDs assigned to this VID.
However, there is a derangement about it.The fee for a vendor ID is $2000 and is extremely high for hobbists. So some private vendor ID owners started to sell PIDs for smaller amounts.
Later USB organisation qualified it illegal.
Some customers pointed out that at the time of buying theirs vendor ID there was no such limitation and continued selling PIDs.
It is your decition what you mean about the story. You may find more at the links below.
http://www.mcselec.com/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=shop.flypage&product_id=92&option=com_phpshop&Itemid=1
http://www.voti.nl/pids/pidfaq.html

Comment: The VID issue isn't really the question, the question was about the HID usage page registration.